# How to do dictionary value comparisons with generic key names?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

My current code is ugly, so I'm looking for a more generic solution:

I have the following example python dictionary, with values as strings:

```
example_dict = {'key1':'AAAAAAAAAAA','key2':'BBBBAAABBBB', 'key3':'CAAAAAAACCC','key4':'DDDAADADAAA'}
```

Note that the strings are the same length, and only contain capital letters:

```
'AAAAAAAAAAA'
'BBBBAAABBBB'
'CAAAAAAACCC'
'DDDAADADAAA'
```

I would like to iterate over these strings, and find the indices whereby the string characters are the same. The following approach is what I'm not doing:

```
for i in range(11):
    if (example_dict['key1'][i]==example_dict['key2'][i]==example_dict['key3'][i]==example_dict['key4'][i]):
        print(i)
```

which works, as we see index 4 and 6 for all strings contain `"A"`.

The problem is, I would like to do the same string comparison with other dictionaries, which have different key names (and more/less items).

For example, if I use the dictionary `ex2 = {'one':'AAAAA', 'two':'ABBBA'}`, I would need to change the above if statement to

```
if (ex2['one'][i]==ex2['two'][i]):
```

Is it possible to do comparisons of python dictionary values without explicitly naming the keys? Naturally, the above could is very ugly----the better question could be, is there a more generic way to do this task?

Comment: @Nick It does---I just wasn't able to find it, or make the connection. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```py
example_dict = {'key1': 'AAAAAAAAAAA', 'key2': 'BBBBAAABBBB',
                'key3': 'CAAAAAAACCC', 'key4': 'DDDAADADAAA'}

for i in range(11):
    index_values = [example_dict.get(k)[i] for k, v in example_dict.items()]
    if (len(set(index_values)) == 1):
        print(i)
```

Comment: I prefer r.ook's answer over mine.

Comment: Nothing wrong with yours - if anything you could simplify the list comprehension to `[v[i] for v in example_dict.values()]`.  Nobody says the shortest code is always the best, yours is more readable than mine :).

Comment: True about the readability but I like the use of zip(), not the most readable function name but for those who knows zip() is like transpose then it's a good use case here.

Comment: I think both answers are great---I'm choosing this, because I think the discussion is helpful. However, r.ook has a perfect answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

A solution exists with `zip` and `list` comprehension:

```
[i for i, x in enumerate(zip(*example_dict.values())) if len(set(x))==1]
```

Result:

```
[4, 6]
```

---

`zip(*example_dict.values())` gives you the following results that line up each key by their index nicely:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'A', 'A'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'),
 ('A', 'B', 'A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A')]
```

All you need to do now is compare that each of these tuples have only one common value (`len(set(x))==1`) and return the index to `list`.  `enumerate` gives you both the value (`x`, zipped `tuple`) and index (`i`).

Comment: I appreciate the explanation! This is a great answer